# SP2013 - Adding a Content Editor web part to a custom layout page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In sharepoint 2013, I have 2 custom layout pages:
1 associated with Content Type = Article Page, and
1 associated with Content Type = Welcome Page.

I add a Web Part zone to both layout pages.
I create a web page from either layout page.
When I edit the web page to fill in the Web Part zone, no Web Part zone appears and this appears in its place: $Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartTitle;

Any clues?

Thanks.

I'm adding the steps of my process hoping that may make things clearer:

1. access desired site.
2. went to Design Manager
3. clicked "Edit Page Layouts"
4. clicked desired custom page layout
5. clicked "Snippets"
6. clicked "Web Parts / Media and Content"
7. clicked "Content Editor"
8. clicked "Copy to Clipboard" 
   then
9. opened custom page layout (.html) in Sharepoint Designer 2013
10. copied the clipbboard contents within the "asp:ContentPlaceHolder" tags
11. saved 
    then
12. returned to browser
13. went back to "Design Manager"
14. and "Publish a Major Version" of the custom layout page 
    then
15. clicked "Add a Page"
16. goto "Page" tab
17. click "Page Layout"
18. select my custom layout page
19. then scroll to examine my new page (while in "Edit" mode) 
    result 
    I see the text "$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartTitle;", 
    but no box for adding content.

Thanks

Comment: Same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Im new to Sharepoint myself, but this sounds like your snippet might be wrong. If you can access the snippet manager, how to do this is on MSDN [SharePoint 2013 Design Manager snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822367.aspx).

Then what you want to do is create the snippet using the snippet manager, try the Content Editor inside the Media and Content section, you can then add this to your MasterPage inside the MainContent user control.

You could try adding this snippet to your PageLayout.html instead of MasterPage.html in place of the current web part thats failing, to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the web part zones from your layout pages.
2. Open the layout page in design manager and navigate to snippet manager.
3. Copy the snippet for web part zone and place them in the layout as desired.
4. Publish the layout.

Hope this will help to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on Step#10 you should put your code inside the following tag:
asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"